# Cannot edit /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, threads

I am currently building a stress testing tool, and as such I need a pretty massive number of threads. I already went through all settings to raise the limit, but there is one last setting, the upper system-wide limit in `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max`, that I can't seem to be able to change.

I tried

```
sysctl -w kernel.threads-max=200000
```

Editing manually with `nano` or `echo`

```
echo 200000 > /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
```

Editing `/etc/sysctl.conf` and running

```
sysctl -f
```

If I run those as `sudo`, I have no error displayed (the new value is even displayed), but when checking again, the value hasn't changed either. When trying to edit the value with `gedit`, it spat an

> invalid argument"

whatever the value I try, even the original one. I had no problem changing the `pid_max` value.

I really have no clue why it refuses my edits, and I haven't been able to find anybody with a similar problem, so I would be very grateful if someone could explain what is happening.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux

Comment: The whole problem is precisely that the simple&obvious method does not work...

Comment: The files in /proc/ are virtual, and can as such not be edited. ( Please try `$ du /proc/` to know there isn't anything! ) .... The setting "kernel.threads-max=200000" is elsewhere ...

Comment: They can be edited, I have done so for other settings, and also modified that one on other machines (test servers running fedora)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The repsonse lies in `man proc(5)`, here is the interesting part:

```
 /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max (since Linux 2.3.11)
                     This file specifies the system-wide limit on the number
                     of threads (tasks) that can be created on the system.

                     Since Linux 4.1, the value that can be written to
                     threads-max is bounded.  The minimum value that can be
                     written is 20.  The maximum value that can be written
                     is given by the constant FUTEX_TID_MASK (0x3fffffff).
                     If a value outside of this range is written to threads-
                     max, the error EINVAL occurs.

                     The value written is checked against the available RAM
                     pages.  If the thread structures would occupy too much
                     (more than 1/8th) of the available RAM pages, threads-
                     max is reduced accordingly.
```

I assume your kernel version is > 4.1, so since 200000 (the number you try) is less than 0x3fffffff, the problem looks like the available RAM in not sufficient.

Comment: Isn't 0x3fffffff more than 2.000.000.000 ? Also, even the original numbers or lower did not work, although it could be indeed related to the limit on  available ram.

Comment: 200,000 is far less than 0x3fffffff, like it is written

Comment: Well google is lying to me or its not hexa then ;p
But anyway, I am pretty sure it's related to available ram, as tweaking the number seem to work now (did not work last time, so must depend on actually used RAM) but as soon as I get too high, it revert to a default of  96062 (which must be calculated from my physical ram)

Comment: Untested, but Wolfram Alpha says 0x3fffffff = 1073741823, so the following should be: 
```echo kernel.threads-max = 1073741823 >> /etc/sysctl.conf```
```echo 1073741823 > /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max```
(http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0x3fffffff)

Comment: James' comment is the only thing that worked for me.